# Display Image with Base64 String from PostgreSql

Tags: javascript, php, postgresql, canvas, base64

I want to display an image that comes from PostgreSql database. My image is saved as bytea in the postgre DB.

So I select my image from a php script :

```
$img = pg_unescape_bytea($row[7]);
$bs64 = base64_encode($img);
```

I see that "pg_unescape_bytea" is mandatory with bytea type, and I encode the result in base64.

So, my Javascript client receive a base64 string, and I try to display it in a canvas.

```
        var canvas = document.getElementById('canvasPrev');
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

        var imageData = ctx.createImageData(200, 200);
        var pixels = imageData.data;

            if (obj[i].image != null) {

                var data = text2ua(obj[i].image);
                var buffer = data;

                for (var j = 0; j < buffer.length; j += 4) {
                    pixels[j] = buffer[j];
                    pixels[j + 1] = buffer[j + 1];
                    pixels[j + 2] = buffer[j + 2];
                    pixels[j + 3] = buffer[j + 3];
                }

                console.log(pixels);
                ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
           }
```

And text2ua function :

```
function text2ua(s) {
   var ua = new Uint8Array(s.length);
   for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
      ua[i] = s.charCodeAt(i);
   }
   return ua;
}
```

I know that my canvas is working because I achieve to display an image by the same way, but that doesn't come from postgre DB.

My result image looks like the original, but the colors aren't good and the image is semi transparent.

The result that I have :

[image: The result]

What I want :

[image: The image that I want]

(Dimensions are the same in reality)

Comment: the smart thing to do is not to store images in databases.

Comment: You could try to just construct a [data-URI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/data_URIs) and use it as source for an image instead of using canvas.

Comment: `'data:image/png;base64,' + obj[i].image` If you need it in the canvas, go via `<img>`

Comment: I already try that, but the image is not valid... obj[i].image is equalt to :

http://pastebin.com/tGRGkLnP